# rvest scraping html content values

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to **scrape** the following page: [link](https://www.cv.lt/employee/announcementsAll.do?regular=true&salaryInterval=-1&interval=2&ipp=1000) in order to create a data frame with 6 columns: position, company and meta (1-5). Unfortunately I don't know how to catch the values in `content` for example  `<meta itemprop="jobLocation" content="Tauragė" />` so the value Tauragė would be used in creating my dataframe (in this example).

My initial code:

```
if(!require("tidyverse")) install.packages("tidyverse"); library("tidyverse")
if(!require("rvest")) install.packages("rvest"); library("rvest")

# setting url and reading html code 
url <- "https://www.cv.lt/employee/announcementsAll.do?regular=true&salaryInterval=-1&interval=2&ipp=1000"
html <- read_html(url, encoding = "utf-8")

# creating a dataframe of ads
ads <- html %>%{
  data.frame(
    position=html_nodes(html, "tbody p a:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text(),
    company=html_nodes(html, "tbody p a:nth-child(2)")%>% html_text(),
    meta1=...
    meta2=...
    meta3=...
    meta4=...
    meta5=... 
)}
```

an example of html code:

```
<td>
    <p itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
        <a href="/valstybes-tarnyba/vsi-taurages-rajono-pirmines-sveikatos-prieziuros-centro-direktorius-taurageje-2-338912727/?sri=83" target="_blank" itemprop="title" onclick="$(this).parents('tr.data').addClass('read');">VšĮ Tauragės rajono pirminės sveikatos priežiūros centro direktorius</a>
        <a href="/viesoji-istaiga-taurages-rajono-pirmines-sveikatos-prieziuros-centras-darbo-skelbimai" target="_blank" itemprop="hiringOrganization" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">Viešoji įstaiga Tauragės rajono pirminės sveikatos priežiūros centras</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="jobLocation" content="Tauragė" />
        <meta itemprop="datePosted" content="2019-08-22" />
        <meta itemprop="employmentType" content="FULL_TIME" />
        <meta itemprop="validThrough" content="2019-09-06T00:00:00.000" />
        <meta itemprop="url" content="https://www.cv.lt/valstybes-tarnyba/vsi-taurages-rajono-pirmines-sveikatos-prieziuros-centro-direktorius-taurageje-2-338912727" />
    </p>
</td>
<td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run this,

```
my_content <- html %>% html_nodes("tbody p meta")  %>%  html_attr("content")
```

After that, by indexing each of them, you can split them into *meta1, meta2,...meta5* like,

```
index <- rep(1:5,101)
meta <- data.frame(Meta= my_content,Index=index)

meta1 <- meta[meta$Index==1,]
meta2 <- meta[meta$Index==2,]
meta3 <- meta[meta$Index==3,]
meta4 <- meta[meta$Index==4,]
meta5 <- meta[meta$Index==5,]
```

**EDIT :**

Another approach is using the `itemprop` values inside `html_nodes()`

```
html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='jobLocation']") %>% html_attr("content")
```

gives only the *Meta1* for you. If you use the `itemprop` values for each *Meta*, you can take the data inside them like,

```
 meta1 <-    html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='jobLocation']") %>% html_attr("content") 
 meta2 <-    html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='datePosted']") %>% html_attr("content") 
 meta3 <-    html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='employmentType']") %>% html_attr("content") 
 meta4 <-    html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='validThrough']") %>% html_attr("content") 
 meta5 <-    html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='url']") %>% html_attr("content")
```

Comment: Thanks, but it creates a single list, which then would be filled in single column. Unfortunately i cannot  select metas like this: `html_nodes("tbody p meta:nth-child(1) ")  %>%  html_attr("content")` else it would work perfectly! Any ideas?

Comment: @JustasMundeikis Ok. I edited the answer wrt  your expected output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Based on your answer I found another way too: to use Xpath, as it allows for selecting the position 

`meta1 = html_nodes(html, xpath = "//p//meta[1]") %>%  html_attr("content")` and so on.

Comment: @JustasMundeikis Something I didn't know...It is also a good way to achieve the goal. Thanks.