# How do you scrape titles and amount of views using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, youtube, rvest

I want to scrape information on Youtube without using YouTube api. I tried using the code below using xpath but it returns character(empty).

```
html <- read_html("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRz2MxhAdJo")
title <- html_nodes(html,xpath = '//*[@id="container"]/h1') %>% html_text()
```

Comment: For the title, I think you can try `html_nodes(html,xpath = '//title')` and then remove the string " - Youtube". It will extract the title element in the head tag. However, for the amount of view, I'm not sure how to extract it using rvest. You may still need to use the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the title and views from the `meta` tags from the webpage.

The title is in the `<meta name="title"` tag.

Example:

```
<meta name="title" content="Avicii - Without You “Audio” ft. Sandro Cavazza">
```

The views (*called interaction*) is in the `<meta itemprop="interactionCount"` tag.

Example:

```
<meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="160908331">
```

For this, you can use something like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57627935/12511801):

```
html %>% html_nodes("[name='title']") %>% html_attr("content") 
html %>% html_nodes("[itemprop='interactionCount']") %>% html_attr("content")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know the meta tag, so it was news to me. The answer was perfect.